# gSOAP alternative in XSD genereated parser

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, gsoap

I'm using gSOAP to generate XML parsing code from XSD Schema I prepared myself. It has nothing to do with web services. The XML data is read from a local file or in memory buffer (by providing proper `istream` to `soap`).

At first it seems simple enough. But now as I use it more and more I'm starting to see some issues.

For example names are introduced in global namespace. It is possible to enforce use of a namespace but then building becomes much more difficult (due to need of generating extra code for error handling), only one namespace can be used and due to use of macros it might cause other issues as well.

And you DO need those namespaces once you have more than one schema per binary building unit (`.exe`, `.dll`, ...)!

So I started to think about some alternative maybe. Especially that I don't need that web services staff. Only automatic code generation for parsing XML based on XSD.

Are there any such alternatives (for native C++)? What are they?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great list of resources about XML data binding:
http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm

Answer (score 0):

The XSD translation by gSOAP's wsdl2h does not yield C++ namespaces but rather maps XSD namespaces to a prefixed name convention (ns__name) that is pretty easy to use and that avoids name clashes in C (and C++). Any binding tool will have to enforce mapping rules of that sort. Why do you state that "And you DO need those namespaces once you have more than one schema per binary building unit"? You can simply run wsdl2h on all XSD together.

Comment: It took almost a year to get some answers! ;)

Comment: Compiling all XSD as one is neither practical nor design-friendly. Consider joning multiple loosly related XSDs from various libs into one, just because all those libs will end up in the same binary module. Does it look any good to you?

Comment: It is a **code generator**, so the old rules of library design modularization do not apply IMHO. You can select any subset of XSD for a project and generate a specialized library. Same concept as the C++ template library (internal code generation): lots of templates to use, but the ones you select to use are instantiated. Just make sure to assign XML namespace prefixes via typemap.dat bindings.